# Pine Script / TradingView - Show Plot Data in Upper Left, but not Plot Lines?

Tags: pine-script

I've made a custom script - I want the values that show in the upper left, but I don't want to actually plot the lines on the chart.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can make the plot transparent. For example, here we set the color to `na` so that the plot is transparent and use `plotshape` instead of `plot` because `plotshape` is by default displayed above the bar (and its values don't affect the chart adjustment):

```
//@version=5
indicator("bar_index", overlay=true, precision=0)
plotshape(bar_index, color=na)
```